# how to compute lengths of all trips from TSP distance matrix in matlab in vectorized fashion

Tags: matlab, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Here is the initial code:

```
n = 5;
D=[0,5,4,3,7;
   5,0,4,6,3;
   4,4,0,5,8;
   3,6,5,0,6;
   7,3,8,6,0];
trips = nchoosek(1:n,2);
```

Now I want to compute the lengths of each of the trips. this can be easily done in the naive fashion.

```
s= zeros(length(trips),1);
for t=1:length(trips)
    s(i) = D(trips(t,1),trips(t,2));
end
```

Can this be done in vectorized fashion? Or any other faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By using `sub2ind`:

```
s = D(sub2ind(size(D),trips(:,1), trips(:,2)))
```